# Do the words with non-palatalized pronunciation of g/c ("get", "give") always have a Germanic origin?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, old-english, consonants, palatalization

In English, *ge*/*gi* is sometimes pronounced as [ge]/[gi], but mostly as [dʒe]/[dʒi]. The second form is explained as palatalization in the topic
[What is the origin of the different pronunciations of C and G before different vowels?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91630/what-is-the-origin-of-the-different-pronunciations-of-c-and-g-before-different-v) The topic connects palatalization with Roman languages.

1. Does the non-palatalized [ge]/[gi] pronunciation as in *get, target, git, give* and [many other words](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:List_of_English_words_where_G_is_pronounced_exceptionally#Hard_.E2.80.9C.E2.80.98g.E2.80.9D_where_soft_.E2.80.9C.E2.80.98g.E2.80.9D_expected) typically mean that the word has a Germanic origin (and is traceable back to the Old English), whilst the palatalized [dʒe]/[dʒi] is a sign of a later Norman ("Latin"/"French") origin?

   Of course I don't mean modern loan words such as geisha, ginkgo :)
2. Are there (non-Greek) words in English where *ce* and *ci* are pronounced non-palatelized [ke]/[ki]? If so, can they also be connected with the Old English (Germanic) origin?

Comment: It’s almost rather the opposite: words where ‹ge› represents [ge] are almost certain _not_ to be inherited words in English. They are almost invariably loan words, most commonly from Old Norse or various stages of German. They are thus Germanic words, but not native English words. Many are not found in Old English at all. _Get_, for example, was snatched from the Vikings and not found until some time in the 12th century, which is at the early period of Middle English. And then of course as Peter writes, they can be loan words from various other languages. _Getsemane_, _ger_, _gibbon_, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, @JanusBahsJacquet: it reinforces my remark about _yet_ and _if_, but I hadn't formulated the case quite like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Always" is a word that is often difficult to maintain in questions of this sort. Certainly most instances of [ge]/[gi] written *ge*/*gi*/*gy* are from Germanic, but not all, as you can easily see by looking through the list you linked to. (By the way, Old English had its own palatalisation, which gives us *yet* and *if*, which once began with 'g').

Similarly, there probably are examples of *ce*, *ci* pronounced [ke], [ki], but I can't think of any. They're certainly very rare, because *k* is normally used instead. Words with this sequence are mostly from Norse, because in Old English the [k] palatalised to [tʃ], now written *ch*. So *church*, Old English *cirice* (cf Northern and Scottish dialect *kirk*, from Norse).

Comment: _Sceptic_ is the only not-obviously-foreign word I can think of that has ‹ce› for /ke/ (others, like _Celtic_, _ceilidh_, and _ecce_ [if you don’t pronounce that /ɛtʃeɪ/, that is], are more obviously non-English). Unless you’re American, of course, in which case it’s _skeptic_ and doesn’t.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Running `oedgrep '<LF>[cC][eiy].*<IPH>(&\w+\.)?k'` yields the headwords *ceilidh, Celt, Celtdom, Celtic, Celticist, Celtish, centum, ceteris
paribus, cist, Cymric, cyne-, cynghanedd,* and *kistvaen*.  If I get cleverer, I’ll figure out how to find midword occurrences, too.  We probably shouldn’t forget Cynewulf either, meaning in this case both his name and his works.

Comment: That’s actually a surprisingly small number—never heard of a kistvaen before (though _cist faen_ makes sense), but I’m a bit disappointed in myself that I didn’t think of _centum_ or _cynghanedd_. Both these words have been part of many conversations in my life this part half-year (_centum_ for a lot longer).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet A more liberal (and **remarkably** more complex) pattern yields *acinaces,
dezincify,
ens necessarium,
faciendum,
lecithotrophic,
lectio difficilior,
neotocite,
ozocerite,
panem et circenses,
Picentine,
psittacine,
psocid,
sacerdotium,
sancta simplicitas,
senecio,
Sicyonian,
tinticite,
zincian,
zincic,
zinciferous,
zincify,* and
*zincite*, many of which admit either /s/ or /k/.  Note that I am not counting “errors” like **demosaicing* or **sandfracing* and such for *demoaicking* or *sandfracking* etc.  Me, I’d go for *dezinkify* to resolve the problem, as with *Orkish*.

Comment: @tchrist Now most of those words I’ll readily admit I’ve never heard or seen in my life. I’ve used _lectio difficilior_ in conversation, but that is, I think, the only non-zinc-related one I’ve ever come across. (I love how they give both a BrE _and_ an AmE pronunciation for _acinaces_.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: "Sceptic is the only not-obviously-foreign word" I guess obvious is a relative notion, but if the Greek origin of that word is not "obvious", I wonder why the non-Englishness of _Celtic_ and _ecce_ would be considered obvious...

Comment: @ColinFine: I have edited my post and replaced "always" by "typically". What I meant was what I call a "statistically always", like when you say "a dog has always four legs and a tail" :)

Comment: @oerkelens I doubt the Greek origins of _sceptic_ are obvious to most non-linguists. I would guess that they can ‘feel’ that _ecce homo_ is not a native English phrase. _Celtic_ could swing either way, though, you’re right about that.

Comment: @Janus: Isn't it the common knowledge that the *sceptics* (skeptikoi) were some kind of Greek philosophers??? It seems very obvious...

Comment: @HonzaZidek Depends on what circles you’re talking about. In literary circles, yes. In the population at large, I’d guess people might have heard about the _σκεπτικοί_, but I doubt they’d make the leap that that’s where the normal English word ‘sceptic(al)’ comes from. More likely, they’ll think it’s the other way around. Just like most people have probably heard of the Qin Dynasty; but outside literary circles, few people probably realise that that is the origin of the name _China_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I am not a linguist, but I may be tainted by marrying a Greek whose mother is a philologist. And maybe I just read too much :P

Comment: @Janus: I will forever remember a funny argument I had with an American girl. She wanted to teach me a word and I told her yes, I know the word, it's Latin. She started violently arguing that no, the word is English! :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: _Celtic_ **does** swing both ways! When it's a football team in Glasgow, it's /s-/.

Answer (score 2):

No. Words with non-palatalized <c> (representing /k/) before  <i>, <e> or <y> are rare, and there is no regular source of them. As Colin Fine mentions, the letter <k> is generally used in these contexts, even for Germanic words.

There are more words with non-palatalized <g> (representing /g/) before <i>, <e> or <y>. However, only some of these are of Germanic origin; there are others from other sources, including, surprisingly, Latin and French.

### Non-palatalized <c>, and  <k>, in words from Latin and Greek

(While you set aside this class of words in your question, I wanted to write a section about them just for the sake of completeness.)
I can think of two words where this occurs, and it is optional in both. The first is the well-known example of *[Celt](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92948/pronunciation-of-celt-k%C9%9Blt-vs-s%C9%9Blt)(ic).* The second is in certain compound words containing "-cephal-" (such as *[encephalitis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/351142/pronunciation-of-the-letter-c-or-ce-in-australian-english)*), where for some weird reason some people use /k/.

A few more words from Greek have /k/ spelled "k" in this context, such as *kinematic* and *keratin.*

For British English speakers, another word with <c> as /k/ before <e> (and obligatorily, not optionally in modern pronunciation) is *sceptic.*

### Non-palatalized <g> in words from Latin and Greek

*Gibbous* comes from Latin, but mysteriously appears to have always been pronounced with hard /g/ (according to the Oxford English Dictionary).

Another word from Latin, *[renege](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269879/why-is-renege-pronounced-with-a-hard-g-sound),* has non-palatalized <ge> because it wasn't actually followed by a front vowel historically; it comes from Latin *renegare.* Formerly, it was spelled with <gue> to indicate the lack of palatalization. This is described by tchrist's answer to the linked question.

The word *gizzard,* according to the OED, comes from an Old French word something like *giser* (modern French *gésier*); the /g/ of the modern English pronunciation is thought to have come from a variant pronunciation that existed in French (as reflected by an alternate spelling *guiser*), but which has not been explained.

The word [*gynecologist*](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2012/09/gynaecology.html?m=1) and the prefix *giga-* used to have pronunciation variants with /dʒ/, but they are now generally pronounced with hard /g/. These words do come from Greek, but we'd expect velar softening to apply anyway.

### Non-palatalized <g> in Germanic words

#### Words inherited from Old English

As Janus Bahs Jacquet mentions in the comments, Old English actually had a similar historical sound change whereby velar consonants (/g~ɣ/ and /k/) were palatalized before front vowels or the front semivowel, although the resulting palatal consonant sounds were still written in Old English with the letters <g> and <c>. In general, Old English palatal <g> corresponds to the Modern English consonant written <y>, and Old English palatal <c> corresponds to the Modern English consonant written <ch>. So words that were spelled with <ge, ce, ci> in Old English generally correspond to Modern English words spelled with <ye, che, chi>. Examples: *yell* (Old English *gellan*), *chest* (Old English *cest*), *child* (Old English *cild*).

Despite this, there are some modern English words with non-palatalized <gi> and <ge> that derive regularly from Old English. In Old English, unpalatalized velar consonants could be found before front vowels in the following environments:

- before the front *rounded* vowel <y> (which generally corresponds to modern English <i>)
- before <e> when it represented the front vowel that developed from umlaut of "o"

So words like *gild* (Old English *gyldan*) and *geese* (Old English *gēs*; umlauted plural of *gōs*) are examples of <gi> and <ge> with non-palatalized /g/ from Old English.

I don't know of any parallel examples of words from Old English spelled with <ci> and <ce> and pronounced with non-palatalized /k/, however. The sound /k/ is regularly spelled in these contexts as <k>: consider the words *king* (Old English *cyning*), *kiss* (Old English *cyssan*), and *keen* (Old English *cēne*).

#### Words borrowed from other Germanic languages

The most important group in this category is loans from Nordic languages, which were not subject to the process of palatalization that affected Old English velars. Norse influence is believed to be responsible for the /g/ in *get* and *give*.

In some cases, however, it is hard to determine if an unexpected /g/ instead of /j/ is due to Norse influence, or developed as part of an Old English dialect for other reasons that we don't know about. For example, I asked a question about the /g/ in "[begin](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/23015/why-does-begin-have-g-instead-of-j-if-its-from-pg-ginnan)" on Linguistics SE, and it seems that the explanation for this development is still somewhat unclear (it could be Scandinavian/Norse influence, but there is no direct evidence of a Norse word with the correct form).

### Palatalized <g> (/dʒ/) in Germanic words

As far as I know, there is no regular Germanic source of *word-initial* /dʒ/ in English. However, /dʒ/ did arise natively in certain contexts, from the long palatalized voiced velar obstruent or the palatalized voiced velar obstruent preceded by a nasal vowel. Word-finally, this usually shows up in Modern English as /dʒ/ and /ndʒ/ spelled <dge> and <nge> respectively. Examples: *brid**ge*** (< OE *brycg*), *twin**ge*** (< OE *twengan*), *sin**ge*** (< OE *(sen(c)gan*).